# Disable all class member functions if the class is empty

Tags: c++

I have a diagnostic drawing class to graphically plot the status of objects in a multithreaded environment. But this is costing me CPU cycles when I don't run in the diagnostic mode. I don't want to check every line for diagnose mode too. Rather I like to a declare the diagnostic object as empty ( or through some other member functions/ extra variables) and all the diagnostic member functions will be rendered irrelevant. Is this possible? I dont't want to change the existing member functions

```
bool dmode = true; // want to avoid this
class plot{
     void draw();
};

class foo{
    void something(){
       plot p;
       if(dmode) p.draw(); // don't want the checking as plot objects are littered everywhere.
    }
};
```

Edited:
// dmode will be decided only at run time based on my settings configuration

Comment: All answers except mine seem to assume that `dmode` is a constant that does not change at runtime. Is that indeed the case?

Comment: @Thomas: `dmode` will be decided only at run time based on my setting configuration

Answer (score 3):

### Compile time discard

You may use `constexpr`:

```
constexpr bool dmode = true;

//...

  if constexpr (dmode) {
```

Using `constexpr` this way will make sure the branch is discarded at *compile time*

---

It should be noted that this is a [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) feature, before that you can use macros to discard code at compile time.

---

A third option is to just rely on compiler optimizations(ie. constant folding), but it is much harder to give any guarentees and might not be feasible for a debug build if that is ever the case.

### Runtime solution

Assuming your `draw` function is `virtual` - you then need to somehow make a non-virtual function to stick the `if` into. Then one way to accomplish this is by making the virtual function private.

```
class plot{
public:
     void draw() {
       if (!dmode) {
           return;
       }
       do_draw();
     }
private://<-- or protected
     virtual void do_draw() = 0;//rename in all subclasses
};
```

However, this is just one way to solve it - without knowing more of the actual case its hard to say which method is more appropriate.

Comment: Do I have to use `if constexpr (dmode)` check in every diagnostic line ?

Comment: I feel like you barely missed the stated question. Performance is only mentioned as a concern regarding the execution of the function body (i.e. the normal `if` would satisfy the performance side of things). The prime focus seems to be on spamming `if` statements around all calls. Edit: See above comment by OP.

Comment: But this way you can discard the whole body of `plot::draw` at compile time, and compiler will optimize away calls to empty function. No need for ifs everywhere, only a single `if constexpr` in `plot::draw()`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: I need to decide only at run time based on my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the check inside the `draw()` function:

```
void plot::draw() {
    if (!dmode) {
        return;
    }
    // Do the actual drawing.
}
```

If that's not an option for some reason, you could make `plot` a pure abstract class, and provide two implementations, `RealPlot` and `NullPlot`. Then create a function `create_plot()` that, depending on the value of `dmode`, returns either a `RealPlot` or a `NullPlot` instance.

Comment: Seems like an realistic  solution to me.  I wait for more answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have options. Here are some of them:

## Concepts - C++20

```
constexpr bool dmode = true;

class plot
{

public:
    void draw() requires (!dmode)
    {
        /* actual implementation */
    }

    void draw() requires dmode
    {
        // empty
    }
};

class foo
{
    void something()
    {
       plot p;
       p.draw();
    }
};
```

## Constexpr if - C++17

```
constexpr bool dmode = true;

class plot
{

public:
    void draw()
    {
        if constexpr (!dmode)
        {
            /* actual implementation */
        }   
    }
};

class foo
{
    void something()
    {
       plot p;
       p.draw();
    }
};
```

## Templated class and an alias - C++11

```
constexpr bool dmode = true;

template <bool Dmode>
class plot_base
{
public:
    void draw()
    {
        /* actual implementation */
    }
};

template <>
class plot_base<true>
{
public:
    void draw()
    {
        // empty
    }
};

template <bool Dmode = dmode>
using plot = plot_base<Dmode>;

class foo
{
    void something()
    {
       plot<> p;
       p.draw();
    }
};
```

## Mock (a.k.a. None of the above)

And ultimately (most likely) none of the solutions are appropriate. It seems to me like what you want is a mock. So look into that.

Comment: `dmode` will be decided at run time, will it work? Your second solution seems promising. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Templated option is beautiful, but would mean much changes in code. I can't touch foo object.

Comment: All my solutions work with dmode set at compile time.